# Migration in main project not detected

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a main project, and some apps:

```
proj
├── proj
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── static
├── manage.py
├── app1
├── app2
└── app3
```

`proj` has some models, but `makemigrations` does not detect them. If I force it:

```
» python manage.py makemigrations proj
App 'proj' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

Well, of course it is not installed: it is not an App: it is the main project! I have not invented this structure: `django-admin startproject` is the one setting it up.

How can I convince django to recognize the models in the main project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Django project layout doesn't expect you to put migrations in `proj/proj`.  If you want to do this, you need to add `'proj'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

A common approach is to create an app e.g.  `core` and put models specific to your project there.